# Filling and submit search with rvest in R

Tags: r, rvest

I am learning how to fill forms and submit with `rvest` in R, and I got stucked when I want to search for ggplot tag in stackoverflow. This is my code:

```
url<-"https://stackoverflow.com/questions"

(session<-html_session("https://stackoverflow.com/questions"))

(form<-html_form(session)[[2]])
(filled_form<-set_values(form, tagQuery = "ggplot"))
searched<-submit_form(session, filled_form)
```

I've got the error:

```
Submitting with '<unnamed>'
Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Follow this question ([rvest error on form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865426/rvest-error-on-form-submission)) I tried several things to solve this, but I couldnt:

```
filled_form$fields[[13]]$name<-"submit"
filled_form$fields[[14]]$name<-"submit"
filled_form$fields[[13]]$type<-"button"
filled_form$fields[[14]]$type<-"button"
```

Any help guys

Answer (score 2):

The search query is in `html_form(session)[[1]]`
As there is no `submit` button in this form :

```
<form> 'search' (GET /search)
  <input text> 'q':
```

this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38387063/13513328) seems to work :

```
<form> 'search' (GET /search)
  <input text> 'q': 
  <input submit> '':
```

Giving the following code sequence :

```
library(rvest)
url<-"https://stackoverflow.com/questions"
(session<-html_session("https://stackoverflow.com/questions"))
(form<-html_form(session)[[1]])

fake_submit_button <- list(name = NULL,
                           type = "submit",
                           value = NULL,
                           checked = NULL,
                           disabled = NULL,
                           readonly = NULL,
                           required = FALSE)
attr(fake_submit_button, "class") <- "input"

form[["fields"]][["submit"]] <- fake_submit_button
(filled_form<-set_values(form, q = "ggplot"))


searched<-submit_form(session, filled_form)
```

the problem is that the reply has a captcha :

```
searched$url
[1] "https://stackoverflow.com/nocaptcha?s=7291e7e6-9b8b-4b5f-bd1c-0f6890c23573"
```

[image]

You won't be able to handle this with `rvest`, but after clicking manually on the captcha you get the query you're looking for :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ggplot
```

Probably much easier to use my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65864978/13513328) with:

```
read_html(paste0('https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=',search))
```

Comment: See my edit, i checked that it now returns ggplot

Comment: `searched$url` should send me this url: `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ggplot` . As you can see `https://stackoverflow.com/questions?q=ggplot` url its not the result related to `ggplot`search.

Comment: The main idea is to be sent to `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ggplot.